# HTTP Request Send Each Byte Individually

Tags: php, vb.net, curl

so in vb.net, the language I'm most familiar with, there is an option to, instead of saying `myrequest.write()`, say `myrequest.writebyte(ValueOfByte)`. This can be done when writing to a file or to an http request stream. I need it for writing to an http request stream.
I was wondering if there was any way to do this is php as I'm not trying to use the normal curl_exec which writes everything at once?
Thank in advance,
Spencer

Comment: What's the reason you want to do this please?

Comment: I'm working on something that requires the request to one file to be milliseconds away from the request to another file. Because of this it is vital that the second request be written all the way except 1 byte and that the last byte be sent as soon as the first post finishes. I know this sounds strange, but it's what I'm developing and I can't seem to find a way to do it in php yet.

Comment: Sounds legit. I'm sure it's possible but in my experience php isn't very quick at writing files.

Comment: That's the thing, it's not writing a file, it's writing to an http request stream.

Comment: Might be worth noting that in the question. I don't know enough about that to help sorry.

Comment: Just added that because i noticed i hadn't before. My apologies.

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak Oh a S8 fan we have here ^.^

Comment: uMobiMob owner. Not really a S8 fan, just a S8 exploiter.

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak Ah I see. Well, I'm not personally too familiar with PHP, more into Perl. Although you could execute the Sanction-Purchase functions at the same time, and just add a minor delay to the purchase, so that it just covers the lapse time. Even milliseconds apart per request would do. 1 millisecond apart per Request. Sanction->purchase lapsing that 1 millisecond.

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak Sorry need to correct myself, not execute the functions, but rather send the request to the server milliseconds apart. Execute at the same time, make the buy function rest for a few seconds... Big fan of your work, or was at least. Nice to see your looking into a browser version rather then only vb... It's not all that easy. although I was able to accomplish it in Perl under 360 lines of code. (not counting the UI addition, just the overall script itself). You probably know who I am, just need to make that connection. Funny walking into you here rather then pal :P

Comment: @Shortland I would assume wesker? Anywho, the problem is that when this is completed in PHP, bounty.php fully executes (the reappend to database) before the whole buy request can execute.

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak Why have the buy not fully execute? Sending the Buy milliseconds after the bounty.php is sufficient enough. (and no, not Wesker, Not to offend him. But I think this is way out of his line. As far as I know he isnt even working on it, some guys named "Anonymous" in his group is...) Also, merging the bounty.php and purchase.php together into one script, would be A LOT more efficient... Having your code execute bounty.php then purchase.php would take up a lot more time, especially since it'd need to get purchase.php from your sever first. Just in opinion merging the script +1

Comment: @Shortland Honestly, and again not to offend him, but I would agree. I called him on having no clue what he was talking about. Anywho, because of the time it takes to get the message back from the server when you do curl_exec, the window to "glitch" is already closed. PHP is beautiful in the sense that when you call curl_exec it automatically executes the code and send back the server response as the return, but it's also ugly because it doesn't allow you to write line-by-line to the request and then call back to the server when you're finished. Also, what do you mean merging the script?

Comment: @Shortland, ran out of room on my last post, but recall that my best language is vb which means that I have probably never seen a merged script xD